# How transaction to backstack works

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, I have a navigation drawer with 3 items. When I click on some item, it loads and replace actual fragment. Fragment A should always save to back stack, so when I click Back, A should be placed on screen with previously saved state. Also, when I click on A in the Navigation Drawer, this same A from back stack with saved state should appear.

I have tried to call onBackPressed since it should do exactly what I need, just load previously saved state of fragment from back stack. But when I press Back or click on A in NavDrawer, nothing happens.

My code

```
public void changeFragment(int position) {
    fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();

    switch(position) {
        // Main fragment; his previous state should be always in back stack
        case 0:
            appBar.setTitle(leftMenuTitles[position]);
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        // Doesn't matter if state is lost
        case 1:
            appBar.setTitle(leftMenuTitles[position]);
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragmentDatabase)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit();
            break;
        // Doesn't matter if state is lost
        case 2:
            appBar.setTitle(leftMenuTitles[position]);
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragmentSettings)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit();
            break;
        // When no fragment found, make me some delicious toast
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "No such position in NavDraw " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    // Close NavigationDrawer

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(leftLinearLayoutNavDrawer);
}
```

So I would be really thankful if someone explaind it for me. What I understand from what have I read, that when I call addToBackStack(), it saves the transaction, not that fargment. And I can't find how to load fragment from back stack without calling onBackPressed(). I have read android developer site and also many questions here, but still I can't figure out how fragment transaction works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re correct in the assumption, that `addToBackStack()` saves the whole transaction – that is, it saves any operation you did on the FragmentTransaction for undoing. This also means, that if you do a `replace()` in the transaction, the previous fragment will be restored when you pop the back stack.

To go back in the back stack, call `get(Support)FragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();`, which undoes the changes of the last transaction added to the back stack.

In any case, you should not call the `onBackPressed()` callback yourself, this is usually called by the android system.

I’ll try to explain it to you via code. In your `onCreate()`, add the first fragment:

```
fragManager.beginTransaction();
    .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragmentMain)
    .commit();
```

Then, when the navigation drawer menu items are pressed, replace the fragment and add to back stack (the replacing is then undone when back is pressed).

```
public void changeFragment(int position) {
    fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();

    switch(position) {
        // Main fragment; his previous state should be always in back stack
        case 0:
            appBar.setTitle(leftMenuTitles[position]);
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragmentMain)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
        // Doesn't matter if state is lost
        case 1:
            appBar.setTitle(leftMenuTitles[position]);
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragmentDatabase)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
        // Doesn't matter if state is lost
        case 2:
            appBar.setTitle(leftMenuTitles[position]);
            fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragmentSettings)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
        // When no fragment found, make me some delicious toast
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "No such position in NavDraw " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Close NavigationDrawer

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(leftLinearLayoutNavDrawer);
}
```

However, I’m not sure if this is exactly what you want. It’s best practice not to use back stack for fragment transactions initiated by navigation drawer menu item selection.

Comment: So when I call get(Support)FragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(); and then commit() it will delete all items from back stack and load last fragment to screen? I have tried it before with popBackStack() and it didn't work, it just deleted back stack.

Comment: No need for `commit()` in this case, since `popBackStackImmediate()` does not return a fragment transaction. It does not delete *all* transactions from the back stack, it undoes the changes from the *last* transaction and then deletes it from the back stack.

Comment: Still doesn't work, it doesn't replace actual fragment with A. It looks simple, yet I can't figure out how to do it. In onCreate() I add A to fragment_holder and save that to backstack. Then, as you see in my code, I replace it with another fragments. But when I click Back or click on fragmentA item in NavDrawer it doesn't do anything, just erase last entry from backstack, so when I click Back again it closes the app (and this shoul stay as it is).

Comment: I understand your problem, but it’s difficult to explain with text only. Your use case is a bit more complex to describe it in simple words. I added some code to my answer, maybe this helps.

Comment: Now it's working as it should. **When I give fragmentMain instance to replace() method, and it is on screen, all changes are made on this instance, and when I call it again in switch(position) it loads same instance (fragmentMain) so it is in a state as it was before it was moved to backstack.** To be honest, I tried this slolution before, but it recreated the fragment as if it was new instance becouse of wrong implementation of lifecycle methods. Thanks, accepting your answer!